# numpy assignment doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Suppose I have the following `numpy.array`:

```
In[]: x
Out[]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [5, 2, 4, 1, 5],
       [6, 7, 2, 5, 1]], dtype=int16)


In[]: y
Out[]: 
array([[-3, -4],
       [-4, -1]], dtype=int16)
```

I want to replace a sub array of `x` by `y` and tried the following:

```
In[]: x[[0,2]][:,[1,3]]= y
```

Ideally, I wanted this to happen:

```
In[]: x
Out[]: 
array([[1, -3, 3, -4, 5],
       [5, 2, 4, 1, 5],
       [6, -4, 2, -1, 1]], dtype=int16)
```

The assignment line doesn't give me any error, but when I check the output of `x`

```
 In[]: x
```

I find that `x` hasn't changed, i.e. the assignment didn't happen.

How can I make that assignment? Why did the assignment didn't happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The the "fancy indexing" `x[[0,2]][:,[1,3]]` returns a copy of the data. Indexing with slices returns a view. The assignment does happen, but to a copy (actually a copy of a copy of...) of `x`.

Here we see that the indexing returns a copy:

```
>>> x[[0,2]]
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 2, 5, 1]], dtype=int16)
>>> x[[0,2]].base is x
False
>>> x[[0,2]][:, [1, 3]].base is x
False
>>>
```

Now you can use fancy indexing to set array values, but not when you *nest* the indexing.

You can use `np.ix_` to generate the indices and perform the assignment:

```
>>> x[np.ix_([0, 2], [1, 3])]
array([[2, 4],
       [7, 5]], dtype=int16)
>>> np.ix_([0, 2], [1, 3])
(array([[0],
       [2]]), array([[1, 3]]))
>>> x[np.ix_([0, 2], [1, 3])] = y
>>> x
array([[ 1, -3,  3, -4,  5],
       [ 5,  2,  4,  1,  5],
       [ 6, -4,  2, -1,  1]], dtype=int16)
>>>
```

You can also make it work with broadcasted fancy indexing (if that's even the term) but it's not pretty

```
>>> x[[0, 2], np.array([1, 3])[..., None]] = y
>>> x
array([[ 1, -3,  3, -4,  5],
       [ 5,  2,  4,  1,  5],
       [ 6, -4,  2, -1,  1]], dtype=int16)
```

By the way, there is some [interesting discussion](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2015-April/thread.html) at the moment on the NumPy Discussion mailing list on better support for "orthogonal" indexing so this may become easier in the future.

Comment: thanks for the np.ix_ and the second example. I wasn't even aware of it