# Numpy array assinging doesn't work (color image with new orders)

Tags: python, numpy

```
colormap[py, px, c] = colors[:, c]

#colormap : (W,H,3) 
#px, py   : (N,)
#c        : int
#colors   : RGB image (N,3)
```

I am trying to assign image with new orders (px,py).
however, the code doesn't seem to be assigning the values

I hard-coded above code to check whether assigning value work as intended

```
print(colormap[py, px, c], colors[:,c])
colormap[py, px, c] = colors[:, c]
print(colormap[py, px, c])
```

output is as follows :
[image]

my numpy version is :: '1.22.4'

Comment: what is existing in colors?

Comment: it's pre-ordered rgb values so the shapes are same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545932/numpy-assignment-doesnt-work

this is most relevent question but ix_ doesn't work in 3d array

Comment: The ... part of your output means that the entire array is too big to be printed and the middle values are not shown. Are you sure that nothing is being changed in your actual array? Also it is difficult to help unless you can provide a small, simple, reproducible example that demonstrates the problem you are facing.